# Does a gapped, local and non-frustration-free 1D Hamiltonian have an exact MPS groundstate?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, spin-chains, tensor-network

(**Fact 1**) It is known that any arbitrary matrix product state (MPS) is a unique groundstate of a gapped, local, and frustration-free *parent Hamiltonian* ([Perez-Garcia et al. 2007](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0608197)). It is by Fact 1, that the AKLT model is the parent Hamiltonian of the AKLT state. Also, it is known (**Fact 2**) that the groundstate of any 1D gapped Hamiltonian can be *well approximated* by an MPS ([Hastings 2007](https://arxiv.org/abs/0705.2024)).

So let me define an exact MPS groundstate, like the AKLT state to the AKLT model, to be an MPS that is not an approximation to the groundstate of the 1D gapped Hamiltonian. Hence, any arbitrary MPS is an exact MPS groundstate to its parent Hamiltonian.

**Question 1**: is the converse of Fact 1 also true? That is, if we construct a local and frustration-free Hamiltonian and prove that it is gapped in the thermodynamic limit, we are guaranteed to have an exact MPS groundstate?

**Question 2**: As a follow-up to question 1, if the Hamiltonian is only gapped and local, and not frustration-free, does that guarantee that the groundstate will not be an exact MPS?

Comment: I suspect both that this is an open problem and that the answer is no. The Hastings paper establishes an upper bound on the error in approximating a gapped ground state by a MPS. You're essentially asking for this bound to be strengthened to zero. I would be interested to see an answer by someone more expert than me.

Comment: Not sure about Question 1, but I think it is not known.  Regarding Question 2, I think the answer is "no", but it might depend how you define "frustration free".  Could you add a formal definition?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch I don't know if this is _the_ formal definition but by frustration-free Hamiltonians, I mean those that are "composed" of projectors onto subspace orthogonal to the (intended) groundstate subspace.

Comment: That's almost certainly not a good definition, since then I can just choose a different positive semidefinite operator with the same kernel.  The typical definition would be that the ground state minimizes the energy of every Hamiltonian term.  But then you can e.g. wonder whether - for non-frustration-free - you might demand this property to be violated for any block length of just for the original Hamiltonian (in which case I'm positive that there are simple counterexamples).

Answer (score 1):

The answer to Question 1 is Yes:

Given a translational invariant, frustration free Hamiltonian, whose ground state degeneracy is bounded for any chain of length $N$ with open boundaries. Then, any translational invariant ground state on the infinite chain for which correlations factorize asymptotically (i.e. $\langle A_0B_n\rangle \to \langle A\rangle\langle B\rangle$) is  a translational invariant Matrix Product State.

This is proven in [T. Matsui, *A Characterization of Pure Finitely Correlated States*. Infinite Dimensional Analysis, Quantum Probability and Related Topics **01**, 647 (1998)](https://doi.org/10.1142/S0219025798000351). (Since this is hard to come by: The result is also quoted in Theorem  IV.17 of our review [Rev. Mod. Phys. 93, 045003 (2021)](https://arxiv.org/abs/2011.12127).)

Comment: Thank you @NorbertSchuch for returning to my question, as I am also returning to the topic that led me to this question.